# Oracle 2-attribute CHECK Constraint Issues

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, check-constraints

I have a table 'Student', and several attributes - two of which are important in this particular problem. I need to make sure that any student with the classification (grade level) of 'junior' has between exactly 55 and 84 hours (credits).

Here's what I have have so far declaration-wise in Oracle (deleted unnecessary code):

```
CREATE TABLE Students (  
id INTEGER,  
name CHAR(10) NOT NULL,  
classification CHAR(10) NOT NULL,  
hours INTEGER,  
gpa NUMBER(3,2) NOT NULL,  
mentor INTEGER,  
-- IC4:  
-- To be classified as a 'junior', a student must have  
-- completed between 55 and 84 hours (inclusive).  
CONSTRAINT IC4 CHECK (classification != 'junior' AND (hours < 55 AND hours > 84))),  
);
```

Oracle throws the error:

```
ERROR at line 23:  
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

I am certain that I haven't formatted the constraint correctly, but my professor spent about 3 seconds on declarations and told us to figure it out for ourselves. I know 1-attribute constraints, but I don't know how to mix and match 2 attributes at the same time. Can someone help me out?

*Essentially in any other code it would look like nested if-statements:

```
if (classification == "junior") {  
    if (hours < 55 && hours > 84)  
        throwSomeError("Foolish!");  
}
```

I just can't seem to translate that into SQL. My apologies if the spacing in this darn thing is bizarre, I can't get it to format to save my life.

Comment: How can hours be less than 55 and greater than 84?

Comment: @sgeddes that could be an answer ;)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669174/oracle-check-integrity-constraint/14669589#14669589)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing comma right at the end, and one too many closing brackets:

```
...84))),);
```

Unless you've cut something out before posting, which may be the case as the error references line 23 (but hopefully not as it's tricky to see a problem in code you can't see at all). What you have compiles if that becomes:

```
...84)));
```

But the condition is wrong anyway, as others have pointed out. One way of getting the result I think you want is:

```
...
CONSTRAINT IC4 CHECK (classification != 'junior' OR hours BETWEEN 55 AND 84)
);
```

The `OR` means that the `hours` check is only applied when the `classification` is `'junior'`, and any other `classification` is not restricted. (If you need different rules for different classifications, have a look at [the very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14669589/266304) Chris Saxon linked to in comments).

With some test data:

```
insert into students values (1, 'A', 'junior', 54, 1, 1); -- ORA-02290
insert into students values (2, 'B', 'junior', 55, 1, 1); -- OK
insert into students values (3, 'C', 'junior', 84, 1, 1); -- OK
insert into students values (4, 'D', 'junior', 85, 1, 1); -- ORA-02290

insert into students values (5, 'E', 'senior', 54, 1, 1); -- OK
insert into students values (6, 'F', 'senior', 55, 1, 1); -- OK
insert into students values (7, 'G', 'senior', 84, 1, 1); -- OK
insert into students values (8, 'H', 'senior', 85, 1, 1); -- OK

select * from students order by id;

  ID NAME       CLASSIFICATION HOURS GPA MENTOR
---- ---------- -------------- ----- --- ------
   2 B          junior            55  1.00      1 
   3 C          junior            84  1.00      1 
   5 E          senior            54  1.00      1 
   6 F          senior            55  1.00      1 
   7 G          senior            84  1.00      1 
   8 H          senior            85  1.00      1 

 6 rows selected
```

`BETWEEN` is inclusive, so this is the same as:

```
CONSTRAINT IC4 CHECK (classification != 'junior' OR (hours >= 55 AND hours <= 84))
```

You might also want a check constraint on `classification`, particularly as this constraint is case-sensitive as it stands; or preferably have a separate `classification` table and have a foreign key constraint on the column in this table. But that's probably out of your control for this assignment.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! One of my classmates, coincidentally, asked the exact same question right around the exact same time as I did last night... bizarre eh?

But anyway, aside from my constraint being ass-backwards (whoops), I did have a few other errors due to the rest of the code (such as the trailing comma), that was throwing Oracle off.

Got it working now, thank you very much gentlemen :)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that `hours` is allowed `Null` and that `CHECK` can't process field that allows `Null`s..

So try making `hours integer Not NULL` and give a default value if your deem..

Also your condition has a mismatch.. check on that too....

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the logic in your constraint might be off.  Hours could never be less than 55 and greater than 84.  Try using OR:

```
CONSTRAINT IC4 CHECK (classification != 'junior' AND (hours < 55 OR hours > 84))
```

However, this doesn't ensure that when classification = 'junior' the hours are between 55 and 84.  Try using this instead:

```
CONSTRAINT IC4 CHECK (classification = 'junior' AND hours >= 55 AND hours <= 84))
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that 'junior' should have value between 55 to 84 then use below compilable code-

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Students 
> ( id INTEGER, 
> name CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
>  classification CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
>  hours INTEGER, gpa NUMBER(3,2) NOT NULL,
>  mentor INTEGER, -- IC4: 
> -- To be classified as a 'junior', 
> a student must have -- completed between 55 and 84 hours (inclusive). 
> CONSTRAINT IC4 CHECK (classification = 'junior' AND (hours >= 55 AND hours <= 84))) ;
> ```